# mysql where clause subquery does not recgnize table alias in outer query

Tags: mysql, subquery

The following query:

```
SELECT wp_users.* 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN  wp_usermeta AS mtct  ON ( wp_users.ID = mtct.user_id )  
WHERE not exists (select * from mtct where mtct.meta_key='City')
```

gives me

> Error Code 1146: Table '.mtct' doesn't exist.

I have searched similar questions but I still can't see what I am doing wrong.  I am using mysql 5.6.21 on centos 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a table alias in the `FROM` clause, you have to use the real table name there.

```
SELECT wp_users.* 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN  wp_usermeta AS mtct  ON ( wp_users.ID = mtct.user_id )  
WHERE not exists (select * 
                  from wp_usermeta AS mtct1
                  where mtct1.meta_key='City')
```

This will fix the error, but I'm not sure if it will give you the results you want. The subquery probably needs to be correlated with one of the tables in the main query. Perhaps this:

```
SELECT wp_users.* 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN  wp_usermeta AS mtct  ON ( wp_users.ID = mtct.user_id )  
WHERE not exists (select * 
                  from wp_usermeta AS mtct1
                  where mtct1.meta_key='City'
                    and mtct1.user_id = wp_users.ID)
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any reason for the join with `wp_usermeta`, since you're not selecting anything from that table. This could just be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE not exists (select * 
                  from wp_usermeta AS mtct1
                  where mtct1.meta_key='City'
                    and mtct1.user_id = wp_users.ID)
```

This will return all the users who don't have a `City` in `wp_usermeta`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem clearly.  Yes, I am trying to get all users who don't have a City set in meta_key field of wp_usermeta.  And your last query works perfectly for that.

Answer (score 0):

Reason has been explained by @Barmar that you can't use an alias in from clause as from clause must have table name, further below query can fulfill your purpose and may be faster in case of bulky tables.

```
SELECT wu.* 
FROM wp_users wu 
LEFT JOIN  wp_usermeta AS mtct  ON wu.ID = mtct.user_id AND mtct.meta_key='City'
WHERE mtct.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I thought about posting this version, too, but decided my answer was long enough as is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, this works for my purpose as well, but I liked the explanation and answer given by @Barmar.

Comment: Barmar wants to say that you are not fetching any data from wp_usermeta table, so there is no requirement to join this table but here concern is which query will give result fast....If this table has less data then Barmar's query can be better option but if this table is bulky then my query may give you better performance, so it has to check by you that which option suits in your environment as here you have various solutions for your problem.